# Parse Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated the Parse Facebook Utils with my application. The problem I'm facing is that when the Facebook App is installed in a Phone, my app opens the in-built Facebook App to make a Login, if I uninstall the Facebook App, then on Login it opens a Custom Facebook like Dialogue to make a Login. Can't figure out why this is happening.

Here's my Login Code:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user == null) //Pressed Cancel Button
            {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Log.d("FaceBookParse -> ", "OnCancel");

            } else if (user.isNew()) //New User
            {


                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                getUserInfo();
                Log.d("FaceBookParse -> ", "OnNewUser");
                editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
                editor.apply();

            } else //Old User
            {
                Log.d("FaceBookParse -> ", "OnOldUser");
                editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you want it to open?

Comment: I want it to open the Custom Dialogue from Facebook not open the Facebook App to make my Login

Comment: It's default functionality of Facebook, If device has install Facebook then the Facebook app will use it only, If Device has not Facebook  install then it will open a browser   for Facebook Login

Comment: In IOS that's not the case

Comment: Is there any why to override that functionality